# Getting an error while trying to print a string in Groovy

Tags: groovy

I try to print the following in Groovy web console

```
def str1=''C:\mkjk\sys''

println str1
```

I get the following error:
Impossible to parse JSON response: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '

Comment: Your code is incomplete. Please post relevant code.

Comment: i'd say, that the groovy web console (groovyconsole.appspot.com) is fun packed with bugs.  i'd rather do my groovy on a local installation.  i also get errors like this in an alert box, but the results from the server are OK.  also there are errors in the firebug console showing up.

Answer (score 3):

It should be:

```
def str1 = 'C:\\mkjk\\sys' // single quotes
```

or

```
def str1 = "C:\\mkjk\\sys" // double quotes
```

or

```
def str1 = """C:\\mkjk\\sys""" // three double quotes (multiline string)
```

or

```
def str = '''C:\\mkjk\\sys''' // three single quotes (multiline string)
```

or

```
def str1 = /C:\mkjk\sys/  // forward slashes (slashy string)
```

Comment: or `/C:\mkjk\sys/` works as well with no need to escape the backslashes

Comment: Feel free to edit. For me it's rather associated with regular expression rather than form of string declaration but works or course and is a valid declaration.

Comment: the same one that i wrote in my question

Comment: you mention a JSON exception, but you've isolated a simple groovy define and print. Your problem is probably elsewhere. Can you show the section around the JSON code?

Comment: Yeah, it seems that this is not problem with printing strings but a JSON parsing problem.

Comment: So it's a problem with the website. U can try write one of the command above in the following console (the one that I used): https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/

Comment: @Sara `''some text''` is still no valid groovy string; note the double single quotes there.

Comment: @Sara is right. It's a problem with the web console.